# Exclude nuget packages from dotCover analysis

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package, dotcover

We're using dotCover as part of our gated check-ins on TFS to ensure code coverage of at least a certain percentage.  I've altered the build process to perform the build, run dotCover and analyse the output but discovered one hiccup when it comes to nuget packages included in the projects.

If a nuget package includes .pdb files, dotCover seems to consider it a fair candidate for analysis and coverage, which totally skews the results.  As a workaround I can remove the .pdb files from the packages included in the solution but it by no way ideal as each update to a nuget package can bring them back.

Note that the VisualStudio interface to dotCover does not suffer from the same issue.

Can anyone suggest a more robust way I can exclude the nuget packages from being included in the dotCover analysis?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried to specify exclude filters?  
  "/Filters=ARG: 
Specifies coverage filters using following syntax: +:module=*;class=*;function=*;
Use -:myassembly to exclude an assembly from code coverage. Asterisk wildcard (*) is supported here."

Comment: @Maria Yeah, tried those but unfortunately they tended to strip all pdb files from the target folder which would result in no code coverage analysis at all.  Theoretically might be possible but totally impractical from what I tried.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Have you specified filters using this pattern -:[module_name]? Or maybe you can just post here the filters that were used? Or, submit a request here: http://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, but I can't even get the exclude filters to work. Ended up submitting a ticket to TeamCity for it (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-48404).

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way I can come up with is explaining how we do it.
We have a solution with a base name: COMPANY.BOUNDED-CONTEXT
All namespaces in all projects defer from it: COMPANY.BOUNDED-CONTEXT.Data.Sql, COMPANY.BOUNDED-CONTEXT.Common, etcetc.

Now when running dotcover we use Assembly filters with only COMPANY.BOUNDED-CONTEXT.*

Comment: I don't think you understand, it was the third party projects that caused the issues, not our own and so not namespaces we could control.  Therefore we could not setup filters easily, as outlined above.  We ended up dropping dotcover in the end, we didn't consider it gave us adequate return on the effort.

Comment: we too had code coverage from nuget packages with pdf files in them. That's why I suggested to filter with an include strategy rather then exclude strategy. Given the fact the question is quite old I answered it so perhaps maybe someone else could benefit from this. Glad you had a soution as well.